# IndexOutOfRangeException in indexed getter

Tags: c#, .net, code-analyst

In my indexed property I check whether the index is out of bounds or not. If it is, I throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

When I run the Code Analyst (in VS12) it complains with CA1065: Unexpected exception in unexpected location.

Referring to the description of CA1065, only

```
System.InvalidOperationException
System.NotSupportedException
System.ArgumentException
KeyNotFoundException
```

are allowed in an indexed getter.

Throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` seems natural to me, so what is the reasoning here?
(And yes, I know I can turn the warning off, I just want to know the reasoning)

Comment: Please post the code for where you throw the exception and where you re catching the exception.

Comment: It is strange. `System.String.this[int]` throws an `IndexOutOfRange`, so this guideline is not followed by a main class in the library.

Comment: @Blam: just out of curiosity: what will this give you?

Comment: If you had some incorrect syntax that you were not aware of

Comment: @Blam -- the syntax is irrelevant here -- Code Analysis does not examine syntax.  What he describes is clear and straight forward.  No code sample is required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of classes use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for this, including [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc). This is a subclass of `ArgumentException` so should satisfy the rule. I guess you could argue that for a vector etc accessed directly, there isn't actually a method call (it is a dedicated opcode - `ldelem*`), so the index in that case isn't *actually* an argument. Seems a weak argument, though.

Comment: I have to disagree on calling an indexer's parameter an index being a weak argument.  As does MSDN. "Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays." via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx -- so why then, shouldn't an indexer behave like an array?

Answer (score 6):

See MSDN: [IndexOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx) is system exception and reserved for accessing array elements. It is thrown by some MSIL instructions: ldelem., ldelema, stelem..

For developing classes use ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Marc beat you to it though :-)

Comment: Also via MSDN (per my reply to Marc): "Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays." -- so again, if the purpose of an indexer is to emulate an array, why would IndexOutOfRangeException be off limits?

Comment: That exception is intended to be used in runtime array bounds check (which could be turned off due optimization). But of course you can use it if you would like :)